# What does one do if he makes a mistake in Brachos before Birkas HaTorah?

Tags: halacha, blessing, mistakes, birchos-hatorah

If one makes a mistake in saying a Bracha (like he started saying a bracha and remembered that he shouldn't say it) after saying "Baruch Atah Hashem", he should finish it off with "lamdeini chukecha" so as to be saying a pasuk from Tehillim 119.

However, before Birkas HaTorah one can't say verses. So what (if anything) should he do (he can't even say "Baruch Sheim" [which is what one should do if he says an unnecessary bracha] since it's a quote from the Gemara)?

Comment: How can he say Al Netillas Yadayim beforehand as it is also a quote from a gemara?

Comment: "However, before Birkas HaTorah one can't say verses." This is a machlokes haposkim (see Shulchan Aruch and Rama OC 46:9). Regarding "Baruch Sheim", the Mishna Berura seems to imply that the Rama holds that it may be recited before Birkas HaTorah even according to the stringent opinion. | Are you asking if avoiding a b'racha l'vatala take precedence over reciting a pasuk before Birkas HaTorah?

Comment: @Fred re the last question: yes (there are sources suggesting that both issues are deoraysa).

Comment: @Fred I don't see a b'racha l'vatala here. There's no Malchus.

Comment: @DoubleAA True, assuming he doesn't continue. He would still be מוציא שם שמים לבטלה though.

Comment: @Fred I don't know about that. He's saying it bederech shevach. What's the problem?

Comment: @DoubleAA The general recommendation to conclude with למדני חוקיך, as mentioned by the Ritva (*Ta'anis* 3b, in the name of Rabbeinu Yonah) and Rabbeinu Yerucham (*Toldos Adam v'Chava* 16:2) and as cited by later poskim such as the *Chayei Adam* (1:24:6,8), suggests that it is a problem.